# Why Are All My Programs Opening When I Call One Function That's Supposed To Start One Program?

Tags: batch-file

I'm tryng to write a batch file which starts programs, but two problems arise:

1. If I use one command, it opens the others (i.e. If I open the calculator, it also opens the curler

Here is the code for my program:

```
@echo off
cls
title Console

:prompt
set /p prompt=: 
goto %prompt%

:help
echo Commands
echo ---------------
echo help........................Shows this list
echo calc........................Starts the CMD Calculator
echo retaskbar...................Starts the Taskbar Fixer
echo curler......................Starts the Curler
echo webping.....................Starts Website Pinger
echo.
pause
goto prompt

:calc
start calc.exe

:retaskbar
start retaskbar.exe

:curler
start curler.exe

:webping
start webping.exe
```

I'm planning to turn this into a single exe file for more convenience.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? I would assume that your code runs from top to bottom if there are no other `goto` usages in the middle

Comment: Cmd.exe reads batch files line by line. If you don't script in a script break such as `goto :Eof`, your script will continue executing each line.

Comment: Note also that using Set /P without performing  any sort of validation leaves your script prone to failure at best, and code injection at worst. Consider using the Choice command for menu task such as this. There are plenty of questions on this site with answers describing how to do so.

Comment: There will be no convenience whatsoever turning this into an exe file. ~First of all it's a batch file, and always will be. If you use one of these converters, they don't actually convert anything. They create a wrapper, (effectively archive), which extracts your batch file into an often hidden and dynamically created temporary location, then runs your batch file as a batch file from there. Not only is this unnecessary overhead, it also means the you will not know the location of the running script, or be able to run anything relative to it.

Comment: So you knew enough to use the Goto to go back to the prompt but not with the other labels?